# Attached DependecyProperty not binding in all directions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently working on a problem with a custom UserControl, I want to expose certain properties of child controls as properties on the parent, I also want data binding to be possible. To make all this happen, I created Attached DependencyProperties on the parent:

```
    //TimeframeSelector.xaml.cs
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableEndFilterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "EnableEndFilter", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(TimeframeSelector), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static bool GetEnableEndFilter(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnableEndFilterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnableEndFilter(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnableEndFilterProperty, value);
    }

    public bool EnableEndFilter
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableEndFilterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnableEndFilterProperty, value); }
    }
```

These Attached DPs are used in the xaml of that control:

```
//TimeframeSelector.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="EveTrader.Wpf.Controls.TimeframeSelector"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:EveTrader.Wpf.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding 
             Path=(ctrl:TimeframeSelector.EnableEndFilter), 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now, the control is used in another control:

```
<ctrl:TimeframeSelector EnableEndFilter="{Binding ApplyEndFilter}" [...]/>
```

The ViewModel for this View supplies a value from user settings, which gets displayed correctly in the control, but any changes made in the control don't go back to the ViewModel.

So the question is: How do I get the control to work both ways? Something already has to work, otherwise the control would be empty (as it was before I added the Inherits flag to the DP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherited values aren't the same as Bindings. When you set a value for a property that was inherited from a parent (as your TwoWay Binding is doing when it writes to the source) it overrides the value that was inherited. Inheritance is 10th out of the 11 [possible value sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

In this case using an attached property with inheritance isn't gaining you anything so you could simplify your XAML a little by just using a standard DP instead.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableEndFilterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "EnableEndFilter", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(TimeframeSelector), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

You can use either an ElementName or RelativeSource Binding to use the parent UserControl directly as a Binding Source which will allow the Binding to work in both directions like you want.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnableEndFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:TimeFrameSelector}}}"/>
```

IsChecked is TwoWayByDefault so you can omit that from the Binding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your UserControl's XAML to:

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc" ...>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=(ctrl:TimeFrameSelector.EnableEndFilter), Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</UserControl>
```